# How to make Python / Nginx / FastCGI automatically recompile code when it is updated/changed?

Tags: python, django, nginx, fastcgi

So I've been working on my first Django / Python project and I got my production server up and running.  I was wondering if it's possible to make Python/FastCGI (not really sure which is responsible for the task) to recompile my code.  As of right now, when I upload updated code, I need to restart the server for the changes to take place.  I read that you can add some kind of mysite.fcgi file to lighttpd so it see's that you've updated the code, can you do the same for Nginx / FastCGI?

Comment: In general you don't want to do that in a production setting because you will have to stat all the files used which typically slows everything down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for anyone else that was interested in my question..  this is only a partial solution, but I ended up finding my answer here:  [How to gracefully restart django running fcgi behind nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361855/how-to-gracefully-restart-django-running-fcgi-behind-nginx)

You can just run the script (I'm going to modify it a bit), everytime you edit your code and it will gracefully restart everything without dropping connections.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [general guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Monitoring_For_Code_Changes) from the mod_wsgi project that outlines how you can monitor code changes from your `app_wsgi.py` and restart the current process if any of the modules have changed. You need to restart the Python process, because threads contending over modules could mean that a freshly reloaded module has outdated references from other modules that are still waiting to get discovered for reload.

If you want something that works nicely with nginx, Django and wsgi apps in general, take a peek at [Spawning](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning) as your wsgi server. It's approach to code reloading is about as graceful as it gets.

It has great documentation, well documented request handling model and it just works, which makes it such a no-brainer to configure. You'd need less than five minutes from now to having your Django instance running on Spawning. Here's another [topical blog](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/spawning-django/) to get your juices running.

Comment: The code monitoring described in Apache/mod_wsgi documentation is for mod_wsgi and would likely not work well, or at all, with other hosting mechanisms.