# catalyst with nginx and fastcgi reload application without downtime

Tags: perl, nginx, reload, fastcgi, catalyst

One of the benefits that's always listed when comparing mod_perl vs. fastcgi, is that for mod_perl you have to completely reload the app and have downtime, but with fastcgi you can reload the app without having downtime. However, I cannot find any examples of how to do this. Is this possible to reload a Catalyst app that's being run using fastcgi without any downtime? I followed this [guide](http://richard.wallman.org.uk/2010/02/howto-deploy-a-catalyst-application-using-fastcgi-and-nginx/) to get my Catalyst app up and running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a script that does what I want by combining this [guide](http://richard.wallman.org.uk/2010/02/howto-deploy-a-catalyst-application-using-fastcgi-and-nginx/)'s script and part of the bash script found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361855/how-to-gracefully-restart-django-running-fcgi-behind-nginx). If you put the script in `/etc/init.d` and then change the appropriate vars at the top, this script can be pretty useful. Calling:

```
service script reload
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/script reload
```

Allows you to have no downtime while the new code loads up. The script can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/xaYjWr4f). You just need to download the script, change the  variables at the top, do

```
chmod +x script
```

and move it into `/etc/init.d`, and then you're good to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  An application running under FastCGI (regardless of whether it uses Catalyst or not) can simply `exit;` and FastCGI will immediately spawn a replacement process, provided that FastCGI has an AppClass defined for that application and the AppClass is configured with a positive `-processes` count.

If there is no AppClass or `-processes` is 0, a replacement process will be created when the next request comes in for the application's URI.  This may cause a slight delay for that first request while waiting for the app to start up, but the request will still be handled normally.

In either case, there should be no moment at which an incoming request will be lost or otherwise fail, provided that the application is allowed to `exit` after completing the current request rather than being interrupted in mid-request (e.g., with `kill -9`).

Comment: so if I were to `kill` each of the pids of my application running underneath FastCGI, these would reload with whatever changes have been made to my application and then I can continue to use it normally?

Comment: Correct. If application processes go away for any reason (killed, exited, crashed...), FastCGI will automatically spawn replacements.

Comment: I see that FastCGI is respawning processes whenever I kill them, however these processes do not seem to have reloaded in the new code, because I am not seeing the changes that I made. However, if I kill the FastCGI process and then start it up again, then I do see the changes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The new child processes are forked from the parent, and unless you restart the parent, code changes are not seen. The secret is to start a new parent, then kill off the old one.